# Updating field (increasing value by 1000) used in foreign key takes very long time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

In my database i have table `message` **InnoDB** which has at the moment only 8 rows. Schema below:

> message: id: { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
>
> user_id: { type: integer, required: false, foreignTable: user, foreignReference: id }
>
> sender_id: { type: integer, required: false, foreignTable: user, foreignReference: id }
>
> subject: {
>   type: varchar(64) }
>
> content: { type: longvarchar }

I need to update `user_id` and `sender_id` fields, as i'm increasing `user.id` itself. For this purpose i'm using such SQL:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
update message set user_id=user_id+10000 where user_id>0;
```

It's executing for **more than 5 minutes**.

I must add, that i'm updating user_id also on other tables, and i have no problem there.

So my question is: what could be possibilites of such slow down? Is it that i have **double foreign key in one table pointing to** `user`? Or can it be refreshing index which is on `user_id`, and separately on `sender_id`?

Additionally:

> AUTOCOMMIT=on;

Comment: How many rows in each table?  InnoDB?  MyISAM?  What value of autocommit?  Using BEGIN...COMMIT?

Comment: @RickJames - as it's in question - it's only 8 rows, `AUTOCOMMIT=on` and it is **InnoDB**

Comment: 5 minutes for UPDATEing an 8-row table.  (I assume nothing else is touching that table for 5 minutes?)  File a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com.